# How to pass dropdown parameters to fetch in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, query-string

I have an array of values from the selected options of a dropdown.I want to pass these parameters using fetch in Django Rest.Everytime,I will be selecting different number of values.
So my,dropdown is like this:

```
 <Select isMulti placeholder="Select Option" options={soptions}   
                         
                         onChange={this.selectValue(this)}/>
selectValue(e){
        var selectValue=this.state.selectValue;
        var isDisplayed=this.state.isDisplayed;
        console.log("the val is:",e);
        console.log("the val is:",e.length);
        console.log("the val is:",e[0].value);
        this.setState({
          selectedValues:e
        });
```

So,my `selectedValues` list keeps changing.So,I want to append this variables to URL using fetch as follows:

```
 fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/values/getallvalueevolution/"+<param here>)
```

How could I send them if they keep changing all the time?
I want to send all the parameters at once

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I don't have time to write a full answer right now, but you'll probably want to look into serializing data, possibly into JSON. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your parameters are in an array you can just append it to the URL

```
const params= ['value1','value2','value3']
let url = "localhost:8080/"+'?'+arr.join('&')
```

that would turn your URL in to `"localhost:8080/?value1&value2&value3"`